# Prove there no integers $x,y$ such that $x+y=100$ and $\gcd(x,y)=3$

Tags: euclidean-algorithm

I have not encountered a problem like this before.I was thinking that there are 2 methods to solve this.
1. Assume $x+y=100$ and then prove that $\gcd(x,100-x)\neq 3$.
2. Assume that $\gcd(x,y)=3$, and then prove that $x+y$ can never equal $100$ for any $x,y\in R$.
I would appreciate a little guidance on the initial setup. Thank you.

Comment: Did you mean that $x + y$ can never equal $100$ for any $x, y \in \mathbb{Z}$?

Comment: Your first method works too: $\,\gcd(x,y) = \gcd(x,100\!-\!x)= \gcd(x,100)\mid 100\,\ $ but $\,3\nmid 100\ \ $

Comment: Method 3: Assume both properties hold, and derive a contradiction.

Answer (score 4):

You can use your second strategy. Indeed, if $3 = gcd(x,y)$ then $3$ divides both $x$ and $y$ and hence $3$ divides $x+y$.

Answer (score 2):

$\gcd(x,y) = 3 \implies 3 \mid x$ and $3 \mid y$, i.e., $x=3m$ and $x=3n$, where $m,n \in \mathbb{Z}$. This means we need $3m+3n = 100$, which is not possible.